# Using a site-packages path for pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm creating a `pyinstaller` spec file and need to add a `DLL` found in a library. This is right now in my own directory here:

```
a = Analysis(['eyecommand.py'],
         pathex=['.'],
         binaries=["C:\users\wwade\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pyvjoy\utils\x64\vJoyInterface.dll"],
         datas=added_files,
         hiddenimports=["skimage.filters.rank.core_cy_3d","pynput.keyboard._win32", "pynput.mouse._win32"],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=True)
```

The problem is I don't want to commit that binary line - it will break on anyone else's machine. Is there a way I can "generically" point to the `site-packages` dir?

```
%SITEPACKAGES%\pyvjoy\utils\x64\vJoyInterface.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [command line switch](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-collect-binaries) `--collect-binaries <package>` if you want to collect dynamic libraries (like the `vJoyInterface.dll` you specified). The option is available in PyInstaller 4.3 or above.

Referr to your question, there's something similar [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#PyInstaller.utils.hooks.get_package_paths) -- a function called `get_package_paths()` which, you can use it like this:

```
import os
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths

pyvjoy_ = get_package_paths('pyvjoy')[1]
os.path.join(pyvjoy_, 'utils', 'x64', 'vJoyInterface.dll')
```

Meanwhile, the `pynput` hiddenimports was not needed, as a new hook for `pynput` was added on `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.3` version.

Comment: Amazing. Extra kudos for the pynput point (but if thats the case - why did that fix our problem)..

I couldn't get the --collect-binaries to alter the error we are finding (that when run it says it cant find he vJoyInterface.dll). So now trying the other approach. Thanks again